# Add items in DataSource object afterwards

Tags: winforms, data-binding, datasource

I am having the following scenario that gives me a headache for some time. 
WinForms app that has a form for showing student details.
In the form we have the student name, the math as a subject and the professor that was assigned for the math subject for that particular student.

The professor field is combo box that shows all math professors. Now some of the math professors are retired, and we don't want to initially list them in the dropdown unless a specific professor is the one that was assigned to the current student.

Datasource is assigned something like this:

```
    myDataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "isRetired = false";
    myCombobox.DataSource = myDataTable.DefaultView;
```

Somewhere below, the databinding is done like this:

```
myCombobox.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("SelectedValue",...
```

How can this be done?
Basically, the question would be: How can I add that one record in the current DataSource object of my combobox that also uses DataBinding?
I tried using the Binding.Format Event to check if the value that comes form the database (e.value) exists in my current DataSource and if it doesn't I tried to add it, but it doesn't work at all. I can't find easy way to add this one row to the current DataSource of my combobox.

When I say it doesn't work I mean that I am only getting the math professors that are not retired that corresponds to the `RowFilter` property.

What I would like to see is for that particular student, even if the professor is currently retired, he (the professor) needs to be listed in this dropdown and selected. But no other retired professors should be listed, only the active ones.

Comment: *Now some of the math professors are retired, and we don't want to initially list them in the dropdown*, ok so when will you know to list them and based on what criteria? On a second thought when you query the db, ask for `isRetired = false OR (isRetired = true AND Prof.ID = Student.ID)`

Comment: @CodingYoshi: Thank you for your answer. 
Unfortunately, it is not that easy. Student - professor scenario was just simplification. It is much more complex than that and the business requirement says we first need to query the TMathProfessors table and later upon a user request to fill the form (or to query the TStudent table) so your answer is not helpful, unfortunately.

Comment: Ok so query all professors and then when the user requests to fill out the form, do what I said above and before you show the form, set the datasource for the combobox to the filtered professors. Does not matter if the rules are complex, the design (approach) will still work.